# exception handling through mvvm android

Tags: android, mvvm, exception, retrofit

I am using MVVM architecture to hit a web service through retrofit in android studio. I have handled the response of the service in my view class. But the problem i am facing is how to handle the exceptions and pass them to my view class. One way is to make constructor in my Bean class and pass both the response and error to it and update UI. But i want more optimised way to handle exceptions inside UI.

Here is my repository code :

```
final MutableLiveData<MyBeanClass> myBeanClass = new MutableLiveData<>();
   ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClientAuthentication().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MyBeanClass> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyBeanClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Response<MyBeanClass> response) {
            if(response.body()!=null) {
                myBeanClass.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Throwable t) {
         //How to handle exceptions here and pass the exception to UI without making constructor in bean class
        }
    });

    return myBeanClass;
```

Comment: One other way is to take another live data for error, set your error to it and observe it on your UI.

Comment: Can u explain it via some code?

Comment: Hi Ashmeet, how were you able to handle it? I am also facing the same issue and unsure of the procedure of handling different error + exception occuring

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the full implementation of the mvvm with error handling.
Firstly create a class with UI State and Resource.

```
public class Resource<T> {

    @NonNull public final Status status;
    @Nullable public final T data;
    @Nullable public final String message;

    private Resource(@NonNull Status status, @Nullable T data,
                     @Nullable String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> success(@NonNull T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.SUCCESS, data, null);
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> error(String msg, @Nullable T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.ERROR, data, msg);
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> loading(@Nullable T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.LOADING, data, null);
    }


    public enum Status { SUCCESS, ERROR, LOADING }
}
```

On your Repository class do

```
public LiveData<Resource<MyBeanClass>> getDetail(String movieId) {
        final MutableLiveData<Resource<MyBeanClass>> myBeanClass = new MutableLiveData<>();
        ApiInterface apiInterface = new ApiClient().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

   Call<MyBeanClass> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyBeanClass>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Response<MyBeanClass> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    MyBeanClass body = response.body();
                    myBeanClass.setValue(Resource.success(body));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Throwable t) {
                myBeanClass.setValue(Resource.error(t.getMessage(),null));
            }
        });

        return myBeanClass;
    }
```

On your viewModel class

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LiveData<Resource<MyBeanClass>> myLiveData;

    public void init(String id) {
        movieLiveData = new MyRepository().getInstance().getDetail(id);

    }

    
    public LiveData<Resource<MyBeanClass>> getMyLiveData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }
}
```

And on your Activity class

```
final MyViewModel viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        viewModel.init(id);
        viewModel.getMyLiveData().observe(this, finalData -> {

            switch (finalData.status) {
                case SUCCESS:
                    loadDetail(finalData.data);
                    break;
                case LOADING:
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "no Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }

        });
```

If it helps, don't forget to vote. Happy coding

Answer (score 8):

Instead of creating two Mutable classes.
You can just create a wrapper object for both error and success state or even loading state

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(msg: String, data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(ERROR, data, msg)
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(LOADING, data, null)
        }
    }
}
```

And then use MutableLive data as this type

```
final MutableLiveData<Resource<MyBeanClass>> myBeanClass = new MutableLiveData<>();
           ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClientAuthentication().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<MyBeanClass> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<MyBeanClass>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Response<MyBeanClass> response) {
                    if(response.body()!=null) {
                    myBeanClass.setValue(Resource<MyBeanClass>.success(response.body));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Throwable t) {
     myBeanClass.setValue(Resource<MyBeanClass>.error(t.getLocalizedMessage()));
                }
            });

            return myBeanClass;
```

You can check out this google sample
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample

Comment: yeah i did this..now my problem is how to handle the exception in the UI..?

Comment: put an integer as a property in your object to indicate the status of the resource  object (Mybeanclass)
for example if the resource is success it will be 1
if the resource is fail it will be 0
in that case u can check the object integer value and whether it is 1 or 0 and handle it

Comment: but my point is how to get the name of particular exception from the repository to the UI?

Comment: using wrapper class case cannot get retrofit data , it break structure of data response

Answer (score 1):

You can interface here. Call interface method from onFailure and provide implementation of that interface from UI side so whenever error, yiu will be onto your UI side

Answer (score 1):

```
public MutableLiveData<String> responseMessage = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> errorMessage = new MutableLiveData<>();                                           ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClientAuthentication().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<MyBeanClass> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyBeanClass>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Response<MyBeanClass> response) {
        if(response.body()==null) {
          //pick server error message
          JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
          Log.d("Error",jObjError.getString("message"))
        }else{
        myBeanClass.setValue(Resource<MyBeanClass>.success(response.body));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Throwable t) {
     Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
     errorMessage.setValue(t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

simply use two MutableLiveData one for success response and other is for errorResponse and update your UI based on these response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how it can be done from your repository code :

```
//Take it globally in your repository class, and provide getter for it.
final MutableLiveData<MyBeanClass> myBeanClass = new MutableLiveData<>();
final MutableLiveData<Throwable> error = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void someApiCallMethod() {
    // In your method call for API
    ApiInterface apiInterface = 
    ApiClient.getClientAuthentication().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MyBeanClass> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyBeanClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Response<MyBeanClass> response) {
            if(response.body()!=null) {
                myBeanClass.setValue(response.body());
            }
            // Even you can handle your response error if it's in your response.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyBeanClass> call, Throwable t) {
            //Set your error live data from here
            error.setValue(t);
        }
    });
}
```

From your `ViewModel` Class, make a method that calls your repo API method and another to provide your live data to be observed on your UI.

Hope it helps !.

Comment: yes i understood it till repository..but i am facing problems in view model...can u please tell me about how to code in view model to get two different types of data i.e. error/response

Comment: Actually answer is pretty old, recently i get to know about how we can wrap both things from here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum. Let me know if it satisfies your case, so that i'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: i am unable to get a solution from this link..i want to get the name of that particular exception which i am getting in my repository class to my view through view model..and i have taken the response from my repo class through view model to my view..but how it can be done in case of any exception..how to take that exception to my view........